# Kobuki auto-docking error

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working with a Turtlebot 2 with a Kobuki base,
I tried to follow the tutorial [http://ros.org/wiki/kobuki/Tutorials/TestingAutomaticDocking](http://ros.org/wiki/kobuki/Tutorials/Testing%20Automatic%20Docking)

I can start the Kobuki node with no error, but as soon as I start the auto-docking nodelet I get this error :

```
Warning: class_loader::class_loader_private: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occured with plugin factory for class (null). New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just dont link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
         at line 180 in /opt/ros/groovy/include/class_loader/class_loader_core.h
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/libkobuki_auto_docking_ros.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9actionlib15GoalIDGeneratorC1Ev
[kobuki-2] process has died [pid 31630, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=kobuki __log:=/home/caroline/.ros/log/3fd781dc-b72b-11e2-a8e9-002354f2e9ef/kobuki-2.log].
log file: /home/caroline/.ros/log/3fd781dc-b72b-11e2-a8e9-002354f2e9ef/kobuki-2*.log
```

Did someone experience the same problem ?
Or does someone have some idea why I get that ?

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62314/kobuki-auto-docking-error/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The module was missing some links to the actionlib library after it got catkinized. This has been fixed, but of course, takes a while to filter through to the public debs. You can either work from source or from the shadow-fixed debs in the meantime.

For others who've had the same problem, the issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/234#issuecomment-16385199).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thanks for your answer, I just updated the package and now it seems to be solved. Thanks.